# Experience Profile shows only One Anonymous Contact

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics, experience-profile

I am using Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0 rev. 180604 (9.0 Update-2) and my Experience profile does not show the Contacts that I have created, except for one Anonymous Contact that existed a month ago. The custom form submit action is supposed to get the details of the user (firstName, lastName, email) and identifies it as a Contact, but Experience Profile does not show it.

So for the steps I have tried (I actually have two variants of code in adding a Contact):

```
public virtual ContactIdentifier CreateContact(string email, PersonalInformation personalInfo)
    {
        var identifier = new ContactIdentifier(ContactSource, email, ContactIdentifierType.Known);
        var identifiers = new ContactIdentifier[] { identifier };

        try
        {
            if (CurrentTracker != null && CurrentTracker.IsActive && CurrentTracker.Session != null)
            {
                CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs(ContactSource, email);
                CurrentTracker.Contact.Tags.Set("isEmpty", "false");
            }

            using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                var knownContact = new Contact(identifiers);
                client.SetFacet(knownContact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInfo);
                client.AddContact(knownContact);
                client.Submit();
            }
        }
        catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Exception creating contact", ex, this);
        }
        return identifier;
    }
```

and the second one which I took the snippet from Sitecore documentation:

```
public virtual bool CreateContact2(string email, PersonalInformation personalInfo)
    {
        if (CurrentTracker.Contact.IsNew)
        {
            var manager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactManager", true) as ContactManager;

            if (manager != null)
            {
                CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.AlwaysSave;
                manager.SaveContactToCollectionDb(CurrentTracker.Contact);

                var trackerIdentifier = new IdentifiedContactReference(Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Constants.IdentifierSource,
                    CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId.ToString("N"));

                using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var contact = client.Get(trackerIdentifier, new ContactExpandOptions());

                        if (contact != null)
                        {
                            client.SetFacet(contact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInfo);
                            client.Submit();
                            manager.RemoveFromSession(CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId);
                            CurrentTracker.Session.Contact = manager.LoadContact(CurrentTracker.Contact.ContactId);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error("Error in creating Contact.", ex, this);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Both of them ran successfully. And I can see my Contacts being created in my SQL Server (**Xdb.Collection.shard0 and shard1**) ContactFacets table:

[image]

Additional details:

- I have enabled my PII and Anonymous indexing
- I also ran the XConnectSearchIndexer -rr to rebuild my Reporting Database
- And also disabled my Robot Detection from [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/disable-the-robot-detection-component-on-a-content-management-server.html)
- And my xConnect services are running, no problem

Am I missing something here?

P.S. I am testing my form via the Experience Editor > Preview mode of the page, does this have an effect?

Comment: Can you see any error in console while you are submitting in preview mode?

Comment: Hi @SwatiGupta, I don't see any exceptions but I can see these in yellow warnings:
- SessionTimeout not found in settings scForm.Settings
- Error: INSTANCE.WEB is not a valid domain. Please add it to the cookie consent manager to authorize the domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add user interaction (either event or goal) before submitting the contact to XDB. I have Updated your first variant code as below:

```
public virtual ContactIdentifier CreateContact(string email, PersonalInformation personalInfo)
    {
        var identifier = new ContactIdentifier(ContactSource, email, ContactIdentifierType.Known);
        var identifiers = new ContactIdentifier[] { identifier };

        try
        {
            if (CurrentTracker != null && CurrentTracker.IsActive && CurrentTracker.Session != null)
            {
                CurrentTracker.Session.IdentifyAs(ContactSource, email);
                CurrentTracker.Contact.Tags.Set("isEmpty", "false");
            }

            using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                var knownContact = new Contact(identifiers);
                client.SetFacet(knownContact, PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey, personalInfo);
                client.AddContact(knownContact);

                // Add User interaction before submit contact
                Guid channelId = Guid.Parse("27A7E0C2-DE17-46C8-8AA3-CFEC0434CCEB");
                var interaction = new Sitecore.XConnect.Interaction(knownContact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, channelId, "userAgent");
                var fakeItemID = Guid.Parse("1D5C266A-112F-4EA2-A69E-E4865ACE2200"); // Replace with real item ID
                PageViewEvent pageView = new PageViewEvent(DateTime.UtcNow, fakeItemID, 3, "en")
                {
                    Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30),
                    Url = "/Home"
                };
                interaction.Events.Add(pageView);
                client.AddInteraction(interaction);

                client.Submit();
            }
        }
        catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Exception creating contact", ex, this);
        }
        return identifier;
    }
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you @Himmat!

Although it makes sense to have a visitor interact with the pages so they could qualify as an organic Contact, I think it should still be appearing in the Experience Profile and that Sitecore should identify it as a Contact with no interaction yet, rather than hiding them even when we have followed the code as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I did it but after doing this I am getting two entries in the experience profile as in the screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LYNotVBvDguaAyghpoOLrIhDOQgDKzd3/view?usp=sharing out of the yellow color one with having Name column as unknown has no data associated (like activity, details) but with the remaining has useful data. I am not sure why two entries are being created.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add at least one `Interaction` like goal or page view event. Below are the code:

```
using (var client = this.CreateClient())
{
                    //Set your facets here
                    // Interaction
                    Guid channelId = Guid.Parse(ChannelId);
                    string userAgent = "Form Update Contact";
                    var interaction = new Interaction(contact, InteractionInitiator.Brand, channelId, userAgent);

                    var ItemID = Guid.Parse(HomeId);

                    PageViewEvent pageView = new PageViewEvent(DateTime.UtcNow, ItemID, 3, "en")
                    {
                        Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30),
                        Url = "/Home"
                    };

                    interaction.Events.Add(pageView);

                    client.AddInteraction(interaction);
                    client.Submit();
}
protected virtual IXdbContext CreateClient()
{
            return SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Swati, yes you're right, it's the Interaction that's missing.